# Manual Django Form Display

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to manually render the form in my template, but what I'm trying is not yielding the expected result, and it is not apparent as to why.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field1'] = forms.BooleanField()
        self.fields['field2'] = forms.BooleanField()
        systems = System.objects.all()
        for i in range(len(systems)):
            self.fields['s' + str(i)] = forms.BooleanField()
        self.fields['field3'] = forms.BooleanField()

        self.initial_fields = [self.fields['field1'], self.fields['field2']]
```

now when I do this in my template:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

it returns what you would expect...after looking up the method `visible_fields` it simply returns a list of fields. So in theory, if I create my own list of fields as with `self.initial_fields`, the form generator should render the following same as above:

```
{% for field in form.initial_fields %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

but instead I get this output in my template:

```
<django.forms.fields.BooleanField object at 0x000001242F51E588> 
<django.forms.fields.BooleanField object at 0x000001242F51E400>
```

I'm assuming I'm missing some initialization of the field itself? I don't understand why one works and the other doesn't. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the bound field object and not the field itself. It's not really a clean way of doing so, but if you are looking to hack around it, you should do like so,

```
...
self.initial_fields = [self.fields['field1'].get_bound_field(self, 'field1'),
                       self.fields['field2'].get_bound_field(self, 'field2')]
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. Now I can do the custom layouts for my forms that I want. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.